# Make a cell's contents visible within a very tall cell

Tags: jquery, html, css

People say a picture is worth a thousand words, so bear this image in mind:

[image]

I've zoomed out the browser for you to understand what I mean. I have this table which has several cells within it. On some occasions, the cell can get really tall (as you can see in the image). If the zoom were set to 100%, changes are that, most certainly, you cannot always read the marked cell's contents. It, simply, might be out of the screen.

I need its contents to be always visible. Is there any CSS or jQuery magic to achieve this?

Here's a fiddle to be cleared: https://jsfiddle.net/fmxw1sb4/

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr><td>Title</td><td>Schedules</td></tr>
  <tr><td rowspan="200" class="content">CCS3</td><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
</table>
```

As you could see there, the title is not visible (it's far too down). As you scroll down to see the other schedules of it, it will become visible... but would disappear again if you keep scrolling.

Thanks in advance. Best regards,
Emiliano

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have tried so far to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution is to make the title fixed and give top:50% if this is the only component you have in the page.

Update your markup to

```
<td rowspan="200" class="content"><div class="title-col">CCS3</div></td>
```

css:

```
.title-col {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

If there are some more components other than the table. Then I suggest a different solution. change .title-col to position: absolute; use javascript to change the top value.

```
var defaultTop =  $('.title-col').offset().top;

$(window).on('scroll', function() {

 if($(window).scrollTop() > $('table .content').offset().top) {
   $('.title-col').css('top', $(window).scrollTop() + defaultTop - $('table .content').offset().top)
 } else {
     $('.title-col').css('top', defaultTop);
 }

});
```

Jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/karthick6891/fmxw1sb4/1/

Comment: Thanks, karthick. I'm afraid it won't be that easy. There are several elements within the page. For starters, there's a header (with the logo, the nav-menu, etc.). Whatsmore, there are  more than one course (for example: CCS3, HTML5). Changing title-col to **position:absolute** would make both titles overlapping.

I've updated your fiddle to illustrate this: https://jsfiddle.net/fmxw1sb4/2/

Any other idea? Thanks in advanced. Best regards,

Emiliano

Answer (score 0):

I think I've already achieved what I was trying to do. You can see it in version 3 of jsfiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/fmxw1sb4/3/)

Try it on your own because it won't work correctly in jsfiddle.

**CSS**

```
.content {
  vertical-align:middle;
  width: 100px;
  position: realtive;
}

.follow {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.enterpriseSpace {
  height:420px;
  width:80%;
  border:1px solid;
  margin:10px 2px;
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align:middle;
  line-height:420px;
  background-color:#909090;
  color:#FFF;
}
```

**JS**

```
function follow() {

var defaultTop = 0;

    var prevH = 0;

    $(".follow").each(function() {

        if( defaultTop ==0) {

            defaultTop = $(this).parent().offset().top;

            prevH = $(this).parent().height();

        }

else {

            defaultTop+=prevH;

            prevH = $(this).parent().height();

        }


        var wScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        var wHeight = window.innerHeight;

        var cellTop = defaultTop;
        var cellBottom = defaultTop+prevH-60;
        var relativeBottom = cellBottom - wScrollTop;
        var up = 0;
        var down = 0;

        if(cellTop <=  wScrollTop+wHeight) {
            if(cellTop > wScrollTop)
                up = cellTop;
            else
                up = wScrollTop;

            if(wScrollTop + wHeight > cellBottom)
                down = cellBottom;
            else
                down = wScrollTop + wHeight;

            $(this).css('top', (up+down)/2);
        }
        else
            $(this).css('top', wScrollTop+cellTop+200);
    });


}

$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    follow();
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    follow();
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="enterpriseSpace">
  Enterprise Logo
</div>
<table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr><td>Title</td><td>Schedules</td></tr>
  <tr><td rowspan="40" class="content"><div id="CSS3" class="follow">CSS3</div></td><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td rowspan="40" class="content"><div id="HTML5" class="follow">HTML5</div></td><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Monday 10:00 to 11:00</td></tr>
</table>
<div class="enterpriseSpace">
  Footer
</div>
```

Comment: Ok, it works because of that typo you have in `.content {position: realtive}`.

Comment: change `.content {position: realtive}` to `.content {position: unset}`